# How to point route to Json file

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have a json file and I want serve that json file but without directly calling the file. I want to use angular routing so that when I route to that link it will display the content of the json file. Is it possible to do this using the angular route?

I have added following line of code to route collection but I am getting error message.

```
 { path: 'test123', redirectTo: 'api/test.json' },
```

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible. You need to get file using controller and then display it in tamplate. Or you can make in production mode folder `api` and place there `test.json` file but you will not have controll over how it will be displayed.